# How to use Yii enum type

Tags: php, yii

How to use Yii enum with code example. i have gone through some examples but not getting  exactly, does anybody know about it,

Answer (score 1):

Two type of enums can be instanced: regular `Enums` and `DBEnums`. The difference is that `DBEnum` enum values must exist in a database table (the ideal scenario for a `DBEnum` is an enumerated value in DB). A check against the database is performed before using `DBEnum` values. Take a look at the examples for further information

to read more visit this http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/enum/ all credit goes to link before